# Why Is Empty Argument Not Getting Identified as Undefined?

Tags: javascript, arguments, parameter-passing

I have an (almost) working solution for a coding challenge:

```js
function addLetters(...letters) {
  let sum = 0;
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  if (typeof letters === 'undefined' || letters === [] || letters === undefined) {
    return 'z';
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    sum += (alphabet.indexOf(letters[i]) + 1);
  }
  if (sum <= 26) {
    return alphabet[sum - 1];
  } else {
    while (sum > 26) {
      sum = (sum - 26);
      if (sum <= 26) {
        return alphabet[sum - 1];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(addLetters())
```

But as you can see, in this particular case of `console.log(addLetters())`, it's returning `undefined` instead of `'z'` - why is that?

I think it must have something to do with the way that `...letters` is a [rest / default / destructured / spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) argument.

The challenge does, in fact, want the argument to appear as a **spread**, but I don't know how to accommodate for it.

**EDIT** Test specs for challenge:

[image]

Comment: The `letters` argument will **never** be `=== []` — they're two different arrays.

Comment: In other words `[] === []` is always `false`.

Comment: Interesting, so then the key is to check for `array.length === 0` as Code Maniac pointed out.

Comment: There's no need to test both `typeof letters === 'undefined'` and `letters === undefined`, they mean the same thing.

Comment: And I don't think a spread argument can ever be undefined, so there's no need to test either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
letters  === []
```

Will always be **false**, as these are ***two different references*** which will never evaluate to true, you need to check the length of array to check if it's empty or not

Also you can safely remove the other two conditions from if statement as `letters` will always be an array

```js
function addLetters(...letters) {
  let sum = 0;
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  if (letters.length === 0) {
    return 'z';
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    sum += (alphabet.indexOf(letters[i]) + 1);
  }
  if (sum <= 26) {
    return alphabet[sum - 1];
  } else {
    while (sum > 26) {
      sum = (sum - 26);
      if (sum <= 26) {
        return alphabet[sum - 1];
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(addLetters())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. :)

```
function addLetters(...letters) {
  let sum = 0;
  const alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'.split('');
  if (!letters.length) {
    return 'z';
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    sum += (alphabet.indexOf(letters[i]) + 1);
  }
  if (sum <= 26) {
    return alphabet[sum - 1];
  } else {
    while (sum > 26) {
      sum = (sum - 26);
      if (sum <= 26) {
        return alphabet[sum - 1];
      }
    }
  }
}
```